# Android httppost response and loading new xml

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am making a login page and using httppost to login on website's php script, But i dont know how to use the httppost response and make it load a new xml when its logged on. 
The response from website should be a "ok" when login its right.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 EditText email,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
 Button logindugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logindugme);

 logindugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

        String a = email.getText().toString();
        String b = password.getText().toString();
        senddata(a,b);

     }

     public void senddata(String a, String b) {

        Runnable r = new Login(a, b);
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
    });
}
```

And a Login class

```
   public class Login implements Runnable {

private String a;
private String b;

    public Login(String a, String b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
  }

   public void run() {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://singiras.eu.pn/s/log.php");

   try {
       // Add your data
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", this.a));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", this.b));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       // Execute HTTP Post Request
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
       if (resEntity != null) {    
           Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
       }

   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

   } catch (IOException e) {
       //
   }






   }
 }
```

Comment: this is bad code. networking have to be handled outside of UI thread, using `IntentService` or `AsyncTask`

Comment: are you getting 'ok' in your response?

Comment: No, server should response. WebnewMobile, can u give me example?

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the parameters into the requested URL using httppost, it solved one similar problem for me.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://singiras.eu.pn/s/log.php?email="+this.a+"&password="+this.b);
```

and remove:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", this.a));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", this.b));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```